# Clojure: How do you apply a function to values at a specific nesting level?

Tags: clojure

I'm a beginner at Clojure so I'll do my best to phrase this as well as I can,

I have a function that returns a list of nested lists
after parsing a dataset of daily temperatures,
each nested list corresponds to daily temps of a specific month e.g Feb 2014, Feb 2015 etc. and is padded out to 31 items using "-999" as filler to retain the dataset's structure.

raw dataset: https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadcet/cetdl1772on.dat

```
(partition 31 (monthly-helper 2 (parse-into-list "CETdataDailyLong")))


=>((-15 7 15 -25 -5 -45 12 47 56 28 20 40 57 38 2 5 25 -3 0 7 7 -3 -10 -10 30 85 46 77 56 -999 -999)
 (0 17 -28 -23 -30 5 -18 -3 -33 -23 -18 -3 -10 50 82 72 62 42 15 57 75 40 92 52 42 62 72 70 -999 -999 -999)
 (-2 -12 4 28 12 0 44 27 -12 16 74 61 76 87 77 78 51 51 59 56 64 52 78 63 39 28 33 81 -999 -999 -999)
 (97 58 75 103 33 46 88 101 56 47 66 36 52 47 58 42 42 37 63 77 76 43 55 85 58 57 55 66 -999 -999 -999)
 (-59 19 28 55 47 30 52 49 42 50 45 25 34 70 40 54 24 13 25 54 85 29 27 38 25 73 44 50 40 -999 -999))
```

I'm trying to remove the -999 values from all nested lists in the list, I need to do this after partitioning the data to avoid having to partition the data arbitrarily by a number of days in each month.
The closest I've got is below but it has no effect as it's only being applied to the top-level list instead of the values in each nested list, How would I need to modify this to get the result I'm looking for, Or to ask my original question;
How do you apply a function to values at a specific nesting level?

```
(remove #(= -999 %)(partition 31 (monthly-helper 2 (parse-into-list "CETdataDailyLong"))))
```

Below is the minimal code with a chunk of the results from my partitioning function, I think it's very close but if you can show me what I'm missing I would really appreciate it, Thanks

```
(remove #(= -999 %)'(((-15 7 15 -25 -5 -45 12 47 56 28 20 40 57 38 2 5 25 -3 0 7 7 -3 -10 -10 30 85 46 77 56 -999 -999)
                     (0 17 -28 -23 -30 5 -18 -3 -33 -23 -18 -3 -10 50 82 72 62 42 15 57 75 40 92 52 42 62 72 70 -999 -999 -999)
                     (-2 -12 4 28 12 0 44 27 -12 16 74 61 76 87 77 78 51 51 59 56 64 52 78 63 39 28 33 81 -999 -999 -999)
                     (97 58 75 103 33 46 88 101 56 47 66 36 52 47 58 42 42 37 63 77 76 43 55 85 58 57 55 66 -999 -999 -999)
                     (-59 19 28 55 47 30 52 49 42 50 45 25 34 70 40 54 24 13 25 54 85 29 27 38 25 73 44 50 40 -999 -999))))
```

I've tried the below and loads of variations on it with map etc, but haven't got anywhere, Seeing a correct example would really help me understand where I'm going wrong.

```
(apply #(remove -999 %) (partition 31 (monthly-helper 2 (parse-into-list "CETdataDailyLong"))))
Exception: Wrong number of args (21) passed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So iiuc, the:

- Overall list contains year lists, and the
- Year lists contain month lists, and the
- Month lists contain the temperatures for the days, and
- The month lists are each padded w/ -999's to make them uniform in size: 31 entries long

What I see that you've tried:

- You've used the `remove` function w/ a predicate to remove if the value equals -999. The value in this case is `'((-15 7 15 -25 -5 -45 12 ...))` which does not equal -999, so you end up w/ what you started with.
- `apply` takes a function and *a single sequence of args*. You passed in 21 lists to `apply`.

With all this probably understood, **I think the easiest solution is a nested `for` loop**. A for loop returns a list of your values, optionally modified by a function. Each value is a list, so you need to go deeper w/ another for loop.

```
; Remove -999's, three levels deep, with for.

(defn remove-999s [s-of-s]
   ; All data
   (for [year s-of-s]
      ; For all years   
      (for [month year] 
         ; For all months
         ; (filter #(not (= % -999)) month) would also work
         (remove #(= % -999) month))))

(remove-999s '(((-15 7 15 -25 -5 -45 12 47 56 28 20 40 57 38 2 5 25 -3 0 7 7 -3 -10 -10 30 85 46 77 56 -999 -999) (0 17 -28 -23 -30 5 -18 -3 -33 -23 -18 -3 -10 50 82 72 62 42 15 57 75 40 92 52 42 62 72 70 -999 -999 -999) (-2 -12 4 28 12 0 44 27 -12 16 74 61 76 87 77 78 51 51 59 56 64 52 78 63 39 28 33 81 -999 -999 -999) (97 58 75 103 33 46 88 101 56 47 66 36 52 47 58 42 42 37 63 77 76 43 55 85 58 57 55 66 -999 -999 -999)(-59 19 28 55 47 30 52 49 42 50 45 25 34 70 40 54 24 13 25 54 85 29 27 38 25 73 44 50 40 -999 -999))))
```

Here's the result, without the -999's.

```
; (((-15 7 15 -25 -5 -45 12 47 56 28 20 40 57 38 2 5 25 -3 0 7 7 -3 -10 -10 30 85 46 77 56) 
; (0 17 -28 -23 -30 5 -18 -3 -33 -23 -18 -3 -10 50 82 72 62 42 15 57 75 40 92 52 42 62 72 70) 
; (-2 -12 4 28 12 0 44 27 -12 16 74 61 76 87 77 78 51 51 59 56 64 52 78 63 39 28 33 81) 
; (97 58 75 103 33 46 88 101 56 47 66 36 52 47 58 42 42 37 63 77 76 43 55 85 58 57 55 66) 
; (-59 19 28 55 47 30 52 49 42 50 45 25 34 70 40 54 24 13 25 54 85 29 27 38 25 73 44 50 40))) [End of data]
```

Because Clojure doesn't allow nested #'s, and nesting `fn`'s gets gross, if you want to use maps like Biped suggests, you'll probably want to use it with `letfn` or `defn`. Here's how I did it:

```
; Remove -999's, three levels deep, with maps.

(defn remove-999s [s-of-s]   
   (letfn [(is-999 [v] (= v -999))
           ( map-month [s] (remove is-999 s))
           ( map-year [s] (map map-month s)) ]
     (map map-year s-of-s))) ; Gives the same results.
```

After writing this, I realized that `for` is like a weird `map`, so either can be used.

Another alternative's `loop` and `recur` or otherwise classic recursion.

Answer (score 2):

i would start with an utility function, updating nested sequences at any level.
it could look like this:

```
(defn update-nested [level f]
  (cond (neg? level) identity
        (zero? level) f
        :else (partial map (update-nested (dec level) f))))

user> ((update-nested 0 (partial remove #{1})) [1 1 0 1])
;;=> (0)

user> ((update-nested 1 (partial remove #{1})) [[1 1 0 1] [0 0 1 0]])
;;=> ((0) (0 0 0))

user> ((update-nested 2 (partial remove #{1})) [[[1 1] [0 1]] [[0 0] [1 0]]])
;;=> ((() (0)) ((0 0) (0)))

user> ((update-nested 3 (partial remove #{1})) [[[[1 1] [0 1]]] [[[0 0] [1 0]]]])
;;=> (((() (0))) (((0 0) (0))))

user> ((update-nested 3 reverse) [[[[1 1] [0 1]]] [[[0 0] [1 0]]]])
;;=> ((((1 1) (1 0))) (((0 0) (0 1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first exhibit is a list-of-lists.  And your desired output is also a list-of-lists -- but different lists.  Therefore, you want `map` instead of `apply`.

Comment: "A specific nesting level" is the realm of more esoteric solutions depending on the shape of data in question.  You can always use map nested in map nested in map... Or, check out assoc-in, update-in, and the clojure.zip functions in the Clojure API at clojure.org. And there are also libraries, such as "meander".

Answer (score 1):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :as s])

(def data '(your list here))

(s/setval (s/walker #(= % -999)) s/NONE data)
```

Comment: I looked up Specter, and it seems exciting: "Clojure's only comparable built-in operations are `get-in` and `update-in`, and the Specter equivalents are 30% and 85% faster respectively".

Comment: That said, I'm new to external libraries and inserting `require` gives `macroexpanding clojure.core/ns` and `No such ns: s` errors.  I'm new to requiring external libraries, and after looking Clojure,org [here](https://clojure.org/reference/other_libraries) and [here](https://clojure.org/reference/namespaces)  and [here](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli), the Specter docs, and SO answers on this [lein install?](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#dependencies), I'm still not sure how to add external libraries. Can you point us in the right direction?

Comment: I've added the dependency in `project.clj`, `lein installed`, placed the `require` both in the code and in the `ns`, tried it w/o the alias, still getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Oh I got it. I use VS Code/Calva. You have to restart it. So 1) Add `[com.rpl/specter "1.1.3"]` to project.clj, 2) require it, 3) because bugs(? reloading w/ C-M-c enter didn't load it), restart the IDE entirely, then this will work.